# Android push notification through rss feed

Tags: android, rss, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have developed a little RSS feed application for my website so basically my goal is that how can I implement push notification with it. I mean whenever I post a new post on my website it should send a push notification to the application.

Comment: What you did for this? post the code and tell us the problem you facing

Comment: You can use android cloud messaging https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html